# Inverted CSS properties to change to RTL

Tags: html, css, web

To change a web page CSS to be RTL from LTR I have to set or invert the following CSS properties:

body{direction:rtl}

any float:left should be float:right and Vice versa

any padding or margin regarding left or right should be reversed

In addition any images should be inverted horizontally.

My question is: are there any more CSS properties should be changed?

Comment: Why do you think images should be inverted? *Some* images may postulate left to right directionality somehow, but that’s a special case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`text-align`, `background-position`, `border` positions, `left` and `right` positions, basically anything and everything that has a horizontal property.

If you would like to do it by hand, you may go through a list of css properties such as [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp), but personally I would look at using one of the online tools to get started.

[CSSJanus](http://cssjanus.commoner.com/) is usually pretty good, though I am sure there are more out there if you google it.

Best of luck.

Comment: Although CSSJanus is good, it is not good if you plan on using it for the following purpose: you have a CSS file with the original LTR layout and you try to create a new CSS file with RTL layout which should be included after the original CSS when the user's lang is RTL. CSSJanus will not overwrite `margin-left: 10px` with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: 10px` but instead just add the `margin-right` property and you end up with both `margin-left` and `margin-right` equal to 10px.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just trying to use right-to-left writing, or are you trying to mirror the webpage?

```
body {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

This will produce a mirror image of the webpage, but everything still works as it should (links are clickable in their new positions, for instance)

Answer (score 3):

Another few properties...

1. **box-shadow and text-shadow**

/* multiply the first value ( horizontal offset of the shadow) by -1 */

```
`box-shadow: 5px -5px 5px 5px #abc;`
```

becomes

```
box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #abc;
```

and

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px #FF0000;
```

becomes

```
text-shadow: -2px 2px #FF0000;
```

2: **border-radius**

You need to be careful with this one as changing the values to achieve rtl works differently here

```
 border-radius:25px 0px 0 25px;


becomes

border-radius:0 25px 25px 0; (not border-radius:25px 25px 0 0;)
```

Also, here are a couple of tips:

1. **Horizontal Positions as Percentages**

If you have a style like:

```
.style
{
position: absolute;
top: 22%;
left: 32%;
...
}
```

the left property would become `100-32=68%`

**2. background-position: Horzontal Value in pixels** - eg:

```
background-position: -34px -85px;
```

In such cases you will have to work this out manually. (See [this](http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/background-images) article)

As a reference:

Here's a [great article](http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/3-different-ways-rtl-your-css) about about converting a website to rtl

actually, the entire website http://rtl-this.com deals with rtl issues so can find lots of useful stuff there

Answer (score 1):

You may try;

```
body {
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Gecko */
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Operah */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* webkit */
  transform: scaleX(-1); /* standard */
  filter: FlipH; /* IE 6/7/8 */
}
```

This will make a mirror effect. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/CdppB/1/)*** is a Live Demo.

You may try `rtl` if you want to flow letters from right to left and may use just `text-align: right` if you want to float items to right.

If you want text to begin from the right, you may try;

```
body{
    unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction:rtl;
    float: right;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/CdppB/2/)*** is the Live Demo;